# full garbage collector is running again and again even when there is sufficient space in heap

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We checked the gc logs for our Java application and found that the full gc is running again and again even when there is enough space in the heap.

Can some please help us understand what can we the reason of this? what can be the cause of invoking the Full GC run again and again when the heap as enough empty space.

Adding sample GC logs

```
157864.497: [GC [PSYoungGen: 54016K->2480K(54592K)] 376436K->327940K(385792K), 0.0237780 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
157864.520: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 2480K->0K(54592K)] [PSOldGen: 325460K->89870K(303168K)] 327940K->89870K(357760K) [PSPermGen: 18527K->18527K(18816K)], 0.7729250 secs] [Times: user=0.75 sys=0.00, real=0.77 secs] 
157865.446: [GC [PSYoungGen: 50944K->1776K(54528K)] 140814K->91646K(357696K), 0.0103750 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

Comment: run with -XX:+PrintGCCause. the fact that it is not enabled indicates that you're on java 7, you probably should upgrade since it reached EOL

Answer (score 0):

If you observe your GC logs, it states that :  [PSPermGen: 18527K->18527K(18816K)] 
which clearly indicates you are running out of PermGen space.

Therefore increase you PermGenSpace further to solve this problems (perhaps by decreasing you heap space a little bit). This can be simply done by using the VM Arg : -XX:MaxPermSize=512m . 512m is the sample size here, you can change it as per your requirement.

Also don't deploy to often on a production system without restarting Tomcat as this will exhaust your PermGenSpace very fast.